# Colocar atributo para ver ocultos en subcarpetas de bat

Tags: batch

se puede colocar este script para que revise todas las sub carpetas y les quite el atributo  Oculto?
  esto es lo que tengo para un bat

```
attrib /s/d -r -a -h -s  C:\Temporal_BackUps\*
```

Comment: Incorrecto, no es `/E`, es `/S` y `/D`, debes fijarte en la ayuda del comando (`/?`), tambien creo que seria necesario que la ruta de direccion termine en `...\*`, aconsejo poner siempre la direcciones entre comillas.

Comment: hice los cambios y aun me arroja error. me ayuda un  poco mas porfavor me dice "Modificador no valido /s/d"

Comment: la respuesta era esta `attrib /s /d -r -a -h -s C:\Temporal_BackUps\* `

Comment: Todos los argumentos se separan por espacios